# "She is on her way to work. " To work is an attribute or Adverbial Modifier?

Tags: infinitives, adverbial-phrases, attributives

> She is on her way **to work**.

The infinitive here can be understood as an attribute or Adverbial Modifier.

which one is right?

Comment: There's no infinitive in the sentence. To is a preposition and work is a noun that means a place of work.

Comment: Thank you. I see. So the "to work" is an attribute of " her way", isn't it?

Comment: I know what is an attribute and adverbial modifier, I think the OP knows as well. because I have searched it and learned it by myself. But that doesn't mean I know it in a sentence, I just not sure about it. That's why the OP ask which one is right, attribute or adverbial, instead of what is it.